# image is not displaying in scene

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, arkit

I am creating an app based on `Augmented Reality`. I have downloaded one 3D object from the internet in `.obj` format and it is converted in a `.scn` format in `Xcode`. When I am running the app camera get started but the image is not added to the scene. I am using ARKit `SceneKitView`

```
import ARKit
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addTapGestureToSceneView()
    configureLighting()
}

func configureLighting() {
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
}


@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}


func addBox(x: Float = 0, y: Float = 0, z: Float = 0)
{
    guard let paperPlaneScene = SCNScene(named: "chair_f.scn"),
        let paperPlaneNode = paperPlaneScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "chair_f",recursively: true)
        else { return }
    paperPlaneNode.position = SCNVector3(x, y, z)
    sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(paperPlaneNode)
}

func addTapGestureToSceneView() {
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTap(withGestureRecognizer:)))
    sceneView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func didTap(withGestureRecognizer recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let hitTestResults = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation)
    guard let node = hitTestResults.first?.node else {
        let hitTestResultsWithFeaturePoints = sceneView.hitTest(tapLocation, types: .featurePoint)
        if let hitTestResultWithFeaturePoints = hitTestResultsWithFeaturePoints.first {
            let translation = hitTestResultWithFeaturePoints.worldTransform.translation
            addBox(x: translation.x, y: translation.y, z: translation.z)
        }
        return
    }
    node.removeFromParentNode()
}




override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    sceneView.session.pause()
}
}
extension float4x4 {
var translation: float3 {
    let translation = self.columns.3
    return float3(translation.x, translation.y, translation.z)
}
}
```

Comment: WIthout checking your code I would suggest trying several different objects. In my first tests many scn objects simply didn't work.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: No. Still waiting

Answer (score 0):

Place your `chair_f.scn` file in `art.scnassets` and access it like below,

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/chair_f.scn")!
```

Thanks.

Comment: Not getting any error. after running the app camera is displaying and when I click on screen nothing is happen

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic .obj file you get from an external source or you want the .obj that is already in the project to be imported to the scene view, I recommend you convert the .obj to .scn as follows:

```
    import SceneKit.ModelIO

    var downloadedNode = SCNNode()


    func convertToScn(sourceUrl: URL){
    let asset = MDLAsset(url: sourceUrl)

    guard let object = asset.object(at: 0) as? MDLMesh else { return }
    downloadedNode = SCNNode.init(mdlObject: object
    //Do what you require in the application using the downloadedNode. Maybe add to your root node.
    }
```

Use it like this :

```
self.convertToScn(destinationUrl: destinationObjectUrl)
```

Here the destinationObjectUrl an url to the location of your .scn/.obj file.

Comment: what is the downloadedNode ?

Comment: a variable of type SCNNode.

Comment: can you tell me how to declare it? it showing me error unresolved identifier 'downloadedNode'

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: what is URL in function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand your concern. 

Have the SceneKit.ModelIO namespace imported to your class.
Have an SCNNode variable named "downloadedNode"
If you have the path to the .obj file or .scn file inside your app, then call the convertToScn(sourceUrl: ) method using the path to the file.

You may then use the downloadedNode as you require in the application. Start with adding it to the rootView, or maybe add a material to the downloadedNode.

Comment: done all the thing but when I call the function by giving source of the file it giving me error of Expected parameter type following ':'

Comment: Can you please share how you called the method?

Comment: self.convertToSCN(sourceUrl: chair_f.obj)

Comment: what is chair_f.obj? Is it just the name of your obj file or is it in your bundle?

How ever, what you need to write in that place is the location of the file inside of your application.

Comment: chair_f.obj is the name of obj file.I kept that file direct in my application. so the path is the only name of the file or should it be different?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens to me, I used the .DAE model and exported to SCN file works for me.